# Using acepack::ace() in R

Tags: r

I am using `ace` function in R. But, i do not want any transformations on the dependent variable. How can i achieve that? I have tried initializing `mon` and `lin` with positive values, but nothing happened.

```
b <- ace(V3, V7, mon = 1, lin = 1)
```

Comment: According to the documentation, it looks like the default is `NULL` so neither would be transformed by default?

Comment: @CephBirk Both will be transformed